# How to pass in a block rather than a variable to a method in ruby that wants a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

Using Rails3, the awesome FactoryGirl gem has a method create_list that takes a strategy, a number of times and then a hash of values to pass into the strategy. (copied from https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)

```
twenty_year_olds = FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, 25, date_of_birth: 20.years.ago)
```

Suppose that instead of passing "20.years.ago", I want to pass a lambda (or Proc) that gets executed once for each time that that the variable gets read. Is this possible in Ruby or FactoryGirl, or would FactoryGirl have to check each param to see if it's a lambda.

```
dob_dynamic = -> { random_dob some_param }
twenty_year_olds = FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, 25, date_of_birth: dob_dynamic )
```

When I did something like this, I got:

```
 raise ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch, message, Object expected, got Proc
```

I worked around this issue by doing something like this:

```
  # pass i, b/c times always passes index to proc
  # dob_dynamic.() invokes dob_dynamic
  create_user = -> i { create :user, date_of_birth: dob_dynamic.() }
  25.times &create_user
```

Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of you want, you should be able to create a new factory (probably using factory inheritance or a trait) and put the randomising code in that factory. If you use a block in a factory it will be reevaluated each time, so you can easily use create_list.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the feature request for the create_list to support taking a proc. For the time being the hook after(:create) is great for code like this, as original posted:

```
# pass i, b/c times always passes index to proc
# dob_dynamic.() invokes dob_dynamic
create_user = -> i { create :user, date_of_birth: dob_dynamic.() }
25.times &create_user
```